# How to change axis values to italic format (Python, Matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib

Currently I'm working on a university bioinformatics project. I have plot with an axis where values should be in italic format (Proteobacteria, Bacteroidata, etc should be in italic), but I can't find any solution how to change format ONLY for one axis values. I have found that using plt.rcParams.update() function can help, but it changes all plot/graph to italic format, but as I said I only need to change only one axis.

My code:

```
color_map = ['#dfdfdf' for i in range(len(order_count))]
color_map[0] = '#e81518'

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(13,7))
ax.barh(phyl_count['Phylum'], phyl_count['Phyl_Perc'], linewidth=0.6, color = color_map)
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
ax.grid(axis='x', alpha=0.4)

plt.xlabel('Percent')
plt.ylabel('Phylum')

for index,data in enumerate(phyl_count['Phyl_Perc']):
    plt.text(x=data+0.1, y=index+0.20,s=f'{data}%')
    

plt.show()
```

And I get this graph, how can I change Proteobacteria, Bacteriodata, etc to italic?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain a list of the labels by writing

```
labels = ax.get_yticklabels()
```

This gives you a list of the labels, where each label is an instance of Matplotlibs [Text](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/text_api.html). This has a `set_style`-method, where one of the options is to set the text `'italic'` so you can do

```
for lbl in labels:
    lbl.set_style('italic')
```